# The new Google sign in with google for web returns 403 forbidden

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-oauth, google-signin

I am trying to migrate the *Sign in with Google* button from the [deprecated method](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in) to [the new approach](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/overview). The code that I have written is the following:

```
const GoogleOmniauthButton = ({ googleClientId, googleOmniauthPath, text }) => {

  const googleOmniauthCallback = async (gapiResponse) => { ... }

  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.type = 'text/javascript'
    script.async = true
    script.defer = true
    script.onload = () => {
      window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
        client_id: googleClientId,
        scope: 'email profile',
        ux_mode: 'popup',
        callback: (response) => googleOmniauthCallback(response.credential),
      })
      window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(
        document.getElementById('buttonDiv'),
        {
          theme: 'outline',
          size: 'large',
        },
      )
      window.google.accounts.id.prompt()
    }
    script.src = 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client'
    document.head.appendChild(script)   }, [])

  return (
    <div id="buttonDiv" />   ) }

GoogleOmniauthButton.propTypes = {   googleClientId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,   googleOmniauthPath: PropTypes.string.isRequired,   text: PropTypes.string.isRequired, }

export default GoogleOmniauthButton
```

[image]

The button is rendered but when the page is loaded I get the following error:

[image]

According to the official documentation of google existing Google Client Ids will not be affected.

The old code that is working is the following:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import styled from 'styled-components'

import Button from 'components/basics/Button'

import GoogleLogo from 'images/colored_google_logo.svg'

const StyledButton = styled(Button)`
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: ${({ theme }) => theme.colors.primary5};

  & > :not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 15px;
  }
`

const GoogleOmniauthButton = ({ googleClientId, googleOmniauthPath, text }) => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)

  // Inject the Google OmniAuth script and when properly loaded, set loading to false
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script')
    script.type = 'text/javascript'
    script.async = true
    script.defer = true
    script.onload = () => window.gapi.load('auth2', () => setLoading(false))
    script.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js?onload=initializeGoogleButton'
    document.getElementsByClassName('google-omniauth-button')[0].appendChild(script)
  }, [])

  const googleOmniauthCallback = async (gapiResponse) => { ... }

  const onGoogleOmniauthClick = () => {
    window.gapi.auth2.authorize({
      client_id: googleClientId,
      scope: 'email profile',
      prompt: 'select_account',
    }, googleOmniauthCallback)
  }

  return (
    <StyledButton type="button" onClick={onGoogleOmniauthClick} disabled={loading} className="google-omniauth-button">
      <GoogleLogo height="15" />
      <span>{text}</span>
    </StyledButton>
  )
}

GoogleOmniauthButton.propTypes = {
  googleClientId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  googleOmniauthPath: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
}

export default GoogleOmniauthButton
```

I can't find how to fix that. Could you please help? Thank you!

Comment: are you loading https ressource on http page ? I would try to replace `https://accounts.google` by `//accounts.google`. (might not be the solution to your issue)

Comment: I tried that  but the same issue persists. If I am not logged in my google account, the first screen to log in to google appears. But after I log in I get this error.